# ArrayStack size

Tags: c++, size

I had this task in C++ where I had to implement a Stack only using arrays (and not using things like Vectors). The teacher gave us an interface to follow and some code to test our ArrayStack on. My problem is that when I create a stack, fill it with 100 elements then empty it the size is 4 (i set 4 for a minimum) and when the teacher code do the same (in the testStack function) the same check fails.

Heres my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <assert.h>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class Stack {
public:
    // Adds new element to the top of the stack
    virtual void push(T x) = 0;
    // Returns the top element AND removes it from the stack
    // If the stack is empty use 'throw std::out_of_range("<human_friendly_message>");'
    virtual T pop() = 0;
    // Returns the top element but does NOT remove it from the stack
    // If the stack is empty use 'throw std::out_of_range("<human_friendly_message>");'
    virtual T top() = 0;
    // Returns the current number of elements in the stack
    virtual int getSize() = 0;
    // Returns the current capacity of the underlying data storage (array)
    virtual int getCapacity() = 0;
    // Returns true if the stack has no elements and false otherwise
    virtual bool isEmpty() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class ArrayStack : public Stack<T>{
private:
    T* data;
    int arraysize;
    int N;

    void resize(int capacity)
    {
        T* copy = new T[capacity];

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            copy[i] = data[i];

        T* p = data;
        data = copy;
        delete [] p;
    }

public:
    ArrayStack(){
        N = 0;
        data = new T[4];
        arraysize = 4;
    }

    ArrayStack(int n){
        if (n < 1) n = 1;

        N = 0;
        data = new T[n];
        arraysize = n;
    }

    bool isEmpty(){ return N == 0; }

    void push(T x)
    {
        if (N == arraysize)
        {
            resize(2 * arraysize);
            arraysize *= 2;
        }
        data[N] = x;
        N++;
    }

    T pop()
    {
        if (isEmpty()){
            throw out_of_range("Can't pop on empty stack");
        }
        else{
            N--;
            T k;
            k = data[N];

            if (N > 0 && N == arraysize / 4 && arraysize/2>=4)
            {
                resize(arraysize / 2);
                arraysize /= 2;
            }
            return k;
        }
    }

    T top()
    {
        if (isEmpty()) throw out_of_range("Can't top on empty stack");
        return data[N - 1];
    }

    int getCapacity()
    {
        return arraysize;
    }

    int getSize()
    {
        return N;
    }

    ~ArrayStack()
    {
            delete [] data; 
    }
};

template<class T>
void testStack(Stack<T> *& stack, int cap = 128) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        stack->push(i);
        assert(stack->top() == i);
    }

    assert(stack->getCapacity() == cap);
    assert(stack->getSize() == 100);


    for (int i = 99; i >= 0; i--) {
        assert(stack->top() == i);
        stack->pop();
    }
    assert(stack->getCapacity() == 4);
    assert(stack->isEmpty());
}

int main() {    
    try {
        Stack<int> * stackI = new ArrayStack<int>();
        testStack(stackI);
        delete stackI;

        Stack<float> * stackF = new ArrayStack<float>(1);
        testStack(stackF);
        delete stackF;

        Stack<double> * stackD = new ArrayStack<double>(65536);
        testStack(stackD, 65536);
        delete stackD;

        Stack<string> * stackS = new ArrayStack<string>();
        stackS->push("string1");
        stackS->push("string2");
        stackS->push("string3");
        stackS->push("string4");

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            stackS->pop();
        }
        assert(stackS->isEmpty());

        cout << "All tests passed!" << endl;

    }
    catch (std::exception & ex) {
        cout << ex.what() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You ideally need to debug this code yourself and determine what the actual issue is, doing this is a useful skill outside of your course. If you're still having trouble provide us with a SSCCE that explains the exact problem.

Comment: `pop()` shouldn't be reducing your capacity. Also your `Stack` needs to have a `virtual` destructor, otherwise when you do `delete stackI` you're leaking the base class members.

Comment: @Barry Why shouldn't `pop()` reduce the capacity ? The teacher's test case clearly shows that it should. And it's perfectly reasonable if you want to be memory efficient.

Comment: memory allocation/deletion takes up too much time when you resize(), if you want to conserve memory use  placement new https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#placement-new

Comment: @ElderBug: And yet memory efficiency is, in 2015, usually secondary to time efficiency. Which is why no standard containers ever reduce capacity.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, as recently as last week, still in 2015, I replaced a vector by a map, to save some of the 128kB my chip has to offer. Anyway, I was just reading OP's code, no judgment, and I don't think speed nor memory is relevant here.

Comment: @ElderBug: That's why I said "usually". If you're in the embedded world then it matters, but that's not the case for the vast majority of people and it probably shouldn't be a default consideration over other factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may have noticed, the problem occurs with the last stack, the one with an initial capacity of 65536.

If you print the capacity just before the failed assertion, you will notice that it's 65536.
It looks like the stack hasn't been resized at all.

Looking at your conditions for when to shrink the storage, there is a required condition that `N == arraysize / 4`.

Since `N` doesn't become greater than 100, and 65536 / 4 is 16384, this condition will never be true.

Replacing `==` with `<=` takes care of it:

```
N <= arraysize / 4
```